# Top n classes of leaf nodes from decision tree

Tags: r, decision-tree, rpart

I'm using `rpart` pacakge of `R` and I want to extract the top 2 predicted classes for the leaf node instead of just the best.
Take `iris` data as an example:

```
fit <- rpart(Species ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width, data = iris)
print(fit)
```

and the output is:

```
n= 150 

node), split, n, loss, yval, (yprob)
      * denotes terminal node

1) root 150 100 setosa (0.33333333 0.33333333 0.33333333)  
  2) Petal.Length< 2.45 50   0 setosa (1.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000) *
  3) Petal.Length>=2.45 100  50 versicolor (0.00000000 0.50000000 0.50000000)  
    6) Petal.Width< 1.75 54   5 versicolor (0.00000000 0.90740741 0.09259259) *
    7) Petal.Width>=1.75 46   1 virginica (0.00000000 0.02173913 0.97826087) *
```

I want to know for each leaf node, say node 7), what is the 2nd best predicted species. By default it only print out the best predicted species `virginica`

More generally, I want to know the top n predicted classes.

Is it possible to extract this information from `fit` without changing the source code of `rpart` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find them through

```
> fit$frame$yval2
                                             nodeprob
[1,] 1 50 50 50 0.3333333 0.33333333 0.33333333 1.0000000
[2,] 1 50  0  0 1.0000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.3333333
[3,] 2  0 50 50 0.0000000 0.50000000 0.50000000 0.6666667
[4,] 2  0 49  5 0.0000000 0.90740741 0.09259259 0.3600000
[5,] 3  0  1 45 0.0000000 0.02173913 0.97826087 0.3066667
```

Or you can see it from

```
fancyRpartPlot(fit)
```

from the rattle package - it is versicolor

[image]

I presume you'd want this for a more complicated thing, but if the tree is simple-ish, the graph will do.

Comment: Was it helpful at all?